# How to use @objc protocol with optional and extensions at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols, swift-extensions

This code does not compile and might sound stupid as it is, but i'll explain why it's so important!

```
@objc protocol p {
    optional func f1()
    func f2()
}

extension p {
    func f1() { }
    func f2() { }
}


class foo: p {
}
```

Compiler says `Type c does not conform to protocol 'p'` and that's maybe because you can not use @objc optional and extensions at the same time (and does not make sence in this scenario either). But consider the following example:

I want to set a selector on a non-optional method defined in protocol in my extension (main reason i used @objc):

`func f1() { }` -> `func f1() { ... #selector(Self.f2) ... }`

And i also want my `f2()` function to have default behaviour. If i mark `f2()` as `optional`, it can not be used in `#selector` because compiler does not know if this method actually exists in the case of need. Sure there're lots of nasty workarounds like global methods, sending `Selector`s to methods as input and etc, but is there a clean way to achieve it?

---

**This is the practical issue**

```
@objc
protocol Refreshable {
    weak var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl? { get set }
    optional func setupRefreshControl()
    func refresh()
}

@objc
protocol ContentLoader {
    func load(reset: Bool)
}

extension Refreshable where Self: ContentLoader {
    func refresh() {
        delay(0.75) { [weak self] in
            self?.load(true)
        }
    }
}

extension Refreshable where Self: UICollectionViewController {
    func setupRefreshControl() {
        let newRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

        newRefreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        newRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Self.refresh), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        collectionView?.addSubview(newRefreshControl)
        refreshControl = newRefreshControl
    }
}
```

Now if a ViewController implements `Refreshable` and `ContentLoader`, it does not find the default `refresh` function, but it does find `setupRefreshControl`. So i figured let's mark `refresh` as optional too, but by doing that, you can not send it to selector any more.

I even tried this:

`func refresh()` -> `optional func refresh()`
and

```
let str = "refresh"
let sel = Selector(str)
```

It silents the compiler yes, but does not work either... rises `unrecognized selector sent to instance....`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your errors. Please consider posting your actual code (from `f1` and `f2` and the relevant code for the class that you want to conform to protocol `p`) so that others and I can help you. Also please explicitly state what you are trying to accomplish as it is very scattered and unclear.

Comment: Optionals are going to be a problem with Objc. Perhaps what you could do is set up several delegates, each for a specific purpose, and that way if the delegate is not set then the associated functions are not called

Comment: @Ike10 Just updated the question :)

Comment: @Feldur exactly! but i need to set a class variable and also send a selector so i have to use @objc, besides what bothers me is that viewController can see `setupRefreshControl` and `refresh`, but the Selector can not!

Comment: I had time to look a little more closely. It looks to me that the problem is that your extensions depend on self, and so the compiler is not going to know at compile time if the selector is going to be valid. I suspect if the where clauses were not present, then your errors would go away. I'm on an iPad at the moment, so I can't test it for you

Comment: @Feldur No, that's not it.

Comment: @farzadshbfn How did you resolve the issue. I also ended up in similar issue.

Comment: @Sandeep I couldn't, but solved my specific problem using Associated Objects and triggering selector on a implemented method attached to an object that I added with `objc_setAssociatedObject`. hope it helps: http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Comment: @farzadshbfn Thanks. If you have solution handy please post it in answers section that will help everyone.

Comment: @Sandeep I did write an answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: @farzadshbfn Awesome. Learnt something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible in swift (because of the way it bridges to `@objc` protocols). But this is a work around(using Obj-c associated objects) to solve the `unrecognized selector sent to instance...` problem.

```
fileprivate class AssociatedObject: NSObject {
    var closure: (() -> ())? = nil

    func trigger() {
        closure?()
    }
}

// Keys should be global variables, do not use, static variables inside classes or structs.
private var associatedObjectKey = "storedObject"

protocol CustomProtocol: class {
    func setup()
}

extension CustomProtocol where Self: NSObject {

    fileprivate var associatedObject: AssociatedObject? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &associatedObjectKey) as? AssociatedObject
        }

        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &associatedObjectKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }


    func setup() {
        let object = AssociatedObject()
        object.closure = { [weak self] in // Do not forget to use weak in order to avoid retain-cycle
            self?.functionToCallIndirectlyWithSelector()
        }

        let selector = #selector(object.trigger)
//      Uncomment next line to test it's functionality
        object.perform(selector)

//      Here, you must add selector to the target which needs to call the selector, for example:
//      refreshControl.addTarget(object, action: selector, forControlEvents: .valueChanged)

        self.associatedObject = object
    }

    func functionToCallIndirectlyWithSelector() {
        print("Function got called indirectly.")
    }
}


class CustomClass: NSObject, CustomProtocol {}

let instance = CustomClass()

instance.setup()
```

I added `Self: NSObject` constraint to be able to test it's functionality in playground, I'm not sure if it's necessary or not.

Comment: Your `associatedObjectKey` isn't safe. Swift does not guarantee pointer stability when taking a reference to a static. The only safe thing is to use a top-level global variable instead of a type-level static.

Comment: @KevinBallard Do you have any documentations on this? I'm gonna change the answer for now, but I want to know why exactly such thing would happen.

Comment: You're taking a reference to the static var with `&associatedObjectKey`. Associated objects doesn't ever look at the value of this, it strictly uses the pointer, so the pointer you pass must always be the same. But Swift doesn't guarantee that `&associatedObjectKey` will always be the same pointer. The only place where the compiler guarantees this (even though the language never does) is for top-level properties. This info comes straight from a compiler engineer.

Comment: That said, an even safer version (one that the language *does* guarantee will work) is using something like `private static let key = NSObject()` and then using `Unmanaged.pasUnretained(key).toOpaque()`. That gives you back the actual pointer value of the allocated object, which will never change.

Comment: @KevinBallard Didn't know, I just tried it this way (like storing Keys for parsing JSONs or Dictionaries in structs) and it was working fine, (and never ran into problems such as leaks or crashes or ... to be honest). But It's good to avoid it as much as possible :). tnx