# swift subclasses used in generics don't get called when inheriting from NSObject

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

**Partial Solution Update at the end!**

Attached is code that produces odd behavior. I copied it out of a swift playground so it should run in one fine.

I created a subclass in my project and passed it to my generic class as the concrete type. However, I quickly noticed that only the base class methods are called. This is shown with `myBase` and `mySub` below. Despite the generic class being instantiated as `<mySub>`, only the base methods are called. The print lines for the subclass are never shown.

Well, I found a simple way around that and that is to not inherit from NSObject. When I used swift native classes, the subclass methods are in fact called. These are secondBase and secondSub.

How do I pass a subclass into a generic class and get the actual subclass to receive calls when inheriting from NSObject?

And why would behavior be different?

```
import Foundation

// The Protocol
protocol P {
    init ()
    func doWork() -> String
}

// Generic Class
class G<T: P> {
    func doThing() -> String {
        let thing = T()
        return thing.doWork()
    }
}

// NSObject Base Class with Protocol
class A1: NSObject, P {
    override required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func doWork() -> String {
        return "A1"
    }
}

// NSObject Sub Class
class B1: A1 {
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override func doWork() -> String {
        return "B1"
    }
}

// Swift Base Class
class A2: P {
    required init() {
    }

    func doWork() -> String {
        return "A2"
    }
}

// Swift Sub Class
class B2: A2 {
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override func doWork() -> String {
        return "B2"
    }
}

print ("Sub class failure with NSObject")

print ("Recieved: " + G<B1>().doThing() + " Expected: B1 - NSObject Sub Class Generic (FAILS)")
print ("\nSub class success with Swift Native")

print ("Recieved: " + G<B2>().doThing() + " Expected: B2 - Swift Sub Class Generic (SUCCEEDS)")
print("")


#if swift(>=5.0)
print("Hello, Swift 5.0")
#elseif swift(>=4.1)
print("Hello, Swift 4.1")
#elseif swift(>=4.0)
print("Hello, Swift 4.0")
#elseif swift(>=3.0)
print("Hello, Swift 3.x")
#else
print("Hello, Swift 2.2")
#endif
```

Output:

```
Sub class failure with NSObject
Recieved: A1 Expected: B1 - NSObject Sub Class Generic (FAILS)

Sub class success with Swift Native
Recieved: B2 Expected: B2 - Swift Sub Class Generic (SUCCEEDS)

Hello, Swift 5.0
```

**Partial solution update**:

Moving the protocol conformance from the base class to the sub class allows the sub class to behave correctly. Definitions become:

```
class A1: NSObject
class B1: A1, P
```

The problem is the base class can no longer be used directly at all when no functionality beyond it is needed. This is mostly an issue if the protocol being conformed to has an associated type. When this is true, you *must* have a concrete class that conforms to the protocol for use in generics.

One use case here is expecting a base class in the generics (with a protocol involving an associated type) which allows something to function without caring what actual sub class was passed in. This actually ends up being a poor man's form of type erasure in some cases. And you can still use the same generic with the subclass.

```
G<A1>()
G<B1>()
```

This was derived from a similar question here: [Generic Class does not forward delegate calls to concrete subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076112/generic-class-does-not-forward-delegate-calls-to-concrete-subclass?rq=1)

Partial options are:

1. remove NSObject and use swift native classes only
2. when NSObject is required, try to separate protocol conformance from inheritance of NSObject

UPDATE ON THE BELOW IDEA: Doesn't Work

> I am going to test if providing an additional layer changes the behavior. Basically have 3 layers, Base class inheriting from NSObject, base Protocol class adding the protocol but inheriting from base and *then* specific classes. If it can distinguish between the base protocol class and the specific subclass in that case, that would be a functional workaround in all use cases. (and may explain why Apple's NSManagedObject works fine)

Still seems like a bug though.

Comment: I can't see any issue in subclasses method call behavior with or without inheriting base class from `NSObject`.

Comment: For me this prints correctly (as you expected) when running the code using an online swift playground and swift 5.0. Maybe you need to try again or restart Xcode or something. Voted to close.

Comment: Now that is interesting. Can you try earlier versions of swift?

Comment: This is happening in the swift playground and two projects for me. Playground is swift 5. Projects are swift 4.2 (I think, will double check, not converted to 5 for sure).

Restarted Xcode. Will restart my computer. Xcode: Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)

Comment: Restarting did not help. Any ideas about what to try next?

Comment: I will try and do a clean reinstall of xcode. as well as clear my xcode preferences and support/cache files.

Comment: Cleared every reference to xcode I could find and reinstalled it. Trying a second time. If this is a bug specific to my system, I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What online playground did you use? I can reproduce this problem on two macs. The second one has never been used for iOS development.

Please try on your mac with latest xcode in swift playground.

Comment: I tried both in a playground and as part of an existing project (using latest Xcode, Swift 5) I had available and I do not get the expected output, I'll remove my vote to close.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson. Now I just need to figure out why it is happening. I just tried to remove NSObject from my classes, but some of the Apple protocols they conform to require it. (or require me to conform to NSObjectProtocol on my own).

Also exploring not using a base class and repeating code or moving shared code to another utility class. It's a real pain.

Comment: Another interesting thing is there are definitely apple classes where this works. For example, NSManagedObject. It inherits from NSObject, and I have subclasses of it representing my models (mostly generated by Xcode). However, passing in those Concrete subclasses appears to work in that case. ( I have not tried switching the generation so I manage the subclasses). But it is conceptually the same thing.

class myGeneric<MyModel> yet I can call the subclasses model specific properties/functions inside there. Means it is probably the mixing of swift and obj-c that is the issue.

Comment: @matt The point there is subclasses of NSManagedObject which also inherit from NSObject do not appear to have this problem. But it may be the addition of a protocol that always breaks it.

Sorry about the code. I was just producing something simple that broke it. Proving I am not insane. Not caring about code style.

I have not looked at release notes. But it happens this way no matter which swift version you pick in Xcode 10.2. (My project uses 4.2). Indicating it's not a swift "version" thing. I just glanced at the generic related things. They don't seem relevant to me.

Comment: @matt I updated the code sample in the question to be cleaner. I think it's 900% better. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @matt that solves it! I tried adding objc to the classes themselves and it did *not* help. I didn't realize we could add it to a protocol. I tried it because that is what nsmanagedobject subclasses do.

Actually, this may not work. Swift Extensions of objc protocols may not work with objc marked protocols. Basically, choose between functional generics and functional extensions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190702/how-to-use-objc-protocol-with-optional-and-extensions-at-the-same-time

I am going to experiment with that before I accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah, my specific class(es) in my project can't use @objc because that protocol can not be represented in objective-c.

Any swift protocol that uses other swift protocol objects don't work. I can follow the chain and mark all my protocols as objc. I don't know what other problems that will cause yet. I haven't had to do it to one with an associated type or other complexy things.

Comment: @matt yeah, I will update the problem. I couldn't just dump my 45 involved classes. In simplifying it, other complexities were lost.

Is it better to create a new question and mark this one as complete?

Comment: Turns out it’s a known bug and a fix will soon arrive. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10285

Comment: @matt this is good to know. Any idea when it will get into xcode?

Put this as an answer and I will mark this as accepted. You prompted both my other solutions. You should get credit for answering the question. Apple fixing it's problems is the real answer here for confirmed bugs.

Comment: OK, edited my answer and undeleted it. Congrats on your (re)discovery and exploration of this bug, and let's hope Swift 5.1 comes out soon and incorporates the fix.

Comment: Accepted. I didn’t earlier because it wasn’t confirmed as something that will be fixed. Now that we know it is fixed in newer swift, the best answer is to wait for the fix. My answers (derived from you) are just ways to avoid the problem. Not solve it.

Comment: @matt FYI: this is not a generics problem. It actually is in the apple release notes, but this problem exists for all swift subclasses of NSObject which is kind of scary to me. see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_1_release_notes

It's only in 10.2.1 release notes. See under swift compiler. There is a workaround with static functions or nonobjc as well stated in the document.

Comment: Yes, I _thought_ I remembered something like this in the release notes, remember? — It's not quite true to say it's not a generics problem. Their illustrative example has no generic, but it relies on a line `let type: Initable.Type = DerivedClass.self`. You'd never say that in a million years. The way this issue can show up in real life is almost certain to be in a generic; where else would a class metatype get cast as a protocol metatype?

Comment: Added the `@nonobjc` workaround to my answer for good measure.

Comment: @matt yeah. I used search. I assumed it was generics specific. At the time I wouldn't have connected the dots between that note and my issue.

Yeah, generics is the likely place you would find this. Ironically I did have some code that did that, but I think it was refactoring from some stupidity I was doing.

nonobjc is the easiest answer assuming you 1) don't use objective-c with the class and 2) don't have inheritance issues with objc functions or protocols.

I am still removing NSObject from my code, cause why keep something I don't need?

Thanks for all the time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to confirm your results and submitted it as a bug, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10617. Turns out this is a known issue! I was informed (by good old Hamish) that I was duplicating https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10285.

In my bug submission, I created a clean compact reduction of your example, suitable for sending to Apple:

```
protocol P {
    init()
    func doThing()
}

class Wrapper<T:P> {
    func go() {
        T().doThing()
    }
}

class A : NSObject, P {
    required override init() {}
    func doThing() {
        print("A")
    }
}

class B : A {
    required override init() {}
    override func doThing() {
        print("B")
    }
}

Wrapper<B>().go()
```

On Xcode 9.2, we get "B". On Xcode 10.2, we get "A". That alone is enough to warrant a bug report.

In my report I listed three ways to work around the issue, all of which confirm that this is a bug (because none of them *should* make any difference):

- make the generic parameterized type's constraint be A instead of P
- or, mark the protocol P as `@objc`
- or, don't have A inherit from NSObject

---

**UPDATE:** And it turns out (from Apple's own [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_1_release_notes)) there's yet another way:

- mark A's `init` as `@nonobjc`

Comment: I already sent a version of mine to apple for code help. I will use this if they continue to "not understand" what is wrong. This is great though! Thanks!

Comment: I have not submitted a bug report. I am using a code help thing from my developer account. If you want to submit the bug report, that's fine with me. I did update my code above to be cleaner, self documenting and show the comparison between NSObject subclass and swift more easily. If you do it I will also happily comment on it if they need more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer so much as a way to avoid the problem.

In most of my code, I did not have to conform to NSObjectProtocol only Equatable and/or Hashable. I have implemented those protocols on the objects that needed it.

I then went through my code, removed all NSObject inheritance **except** on those classes which inherit from an Apple protocol or object that requires it (Like UITableViewDataSource).

The classes that are required to inherit from NSObject are Generic but they are not typically handed into other Generic classes. Therefore the inheritance works fine. In my MVVM pattern these tend to be the intermediate classes that work with view controllers to make logic like table views reusable. I have a tableController class that conforms to the UITableView protocols and accepts 3 generic viewModel types allowing it to provide the table logic for 95% of my views with no modifications. And when it needs it, subclasses easily provide alternate logic.

This is a better strategy as I am no longer randomly using NSObject for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a second way to avoid the problem.

@matt originally suggested this but then deleted his answer. It is a good way to avoid the problem. His answer was simple. Mark the protocol with objc like this:

```
// The Protocol
@objc protocol P {
    init ()
    func doWork() -> String
}
```

This solves the above sample code and you now get the expected results. But doing this has side effects for swift. At least one of those is here:

[How to use @objc protocol with optional and extensions at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190702/how-to-use-objc-protocol-with-optional-and-extensions-at-the-same-time)

For me, it began a chain of having to make all my protocols objc compatible. That made the change not worth it for my code base. I was also using extensions.

I decided to stay with my original answer at least until Apple fixes this bug or there is a less invasive solution.

I thought this one should be documented in case it helps someone else facing this problem.